# Best way to study a new type of database if you are experienced in another type

Tags: oracle, mongodb, learning

Does anyone have a good approach to learning a new type of database when they already are proficient in another one? I have thought about writing notes to myself about how to do various tasks that I am familiar with on the old db and showing the equivalent in the new one.

For example, I like to read manuals. But should I just read through a manual without taking any notes or should I read a section of a manual that corresponds to something I know on my main db and write a quick document about what I just learned?

If anyone has an approach that worked well for them I would love to hear about it.

Bobby

P.S. I am an Oracle DBA learning MongoDB.

Comment: I was in a somewhat similar situation few years back (I am not DBA oriented, though); I was learning for knowing new tools and technologies, I found MongoDB University Courses helpful, the product documentation not too overwhelming and rest is my own effort. You can also download a free edition of the database and try some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Start reading documents, for MongoDB read [MongoDB Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/). Then visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb and try to find solution for the questions from other people - that's where I learned a lot.

Just one tip: don't try to translate SQL commands to NoSQL strictly line-by-line. It works for the very basic commands (see [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) and [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)) but for the more advance topics you should try to leave your Oracle mindset.

Answer (score 0):

As always,  start with their version of The Concepts Guide.

Study it as you would an on-line class.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I did with Oracle. I guess there are no short cuts.

Comment: _"I guess there are no short cuts"_   A truism for all of life, not just learning about a database.  I'm coming up on my 70th birthday, have just retired from a 40-year career in IT - starting before it was called that. I just shake my head in sorrow when, almost daily, I see someone posting looking for a shortcut to something.